# Are there any alternatives to json_decode?

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON string that passes the checks in http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html, which returns:

```
The JSON input is valid in JavaScript.
The JSON input is valid according to RFC 4627 (JSON specfication).
```

However, when I run:

```
$string = json_decode($string);
print_r($string);
```

It prints the string exactly the same way it was before the `json_decode($string)`.

Is there something else I can try? Or maybe something I don't know or didn't think about?

The string is here: http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=marketdatav2

---

To get the string, I was using:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=marketdatav2");
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
```

and then

```
$ret = substr($ret, 0,-1);
```

As it returned a 1 at the end, although I had originally tried it without removing the last character and got the same result.

Comment: can could you print $string here please?

Comment: There are a few options you can change in `json_decode` - have you tried those? Also, err, can we see the string in question? I'll undownvote if you fix.

Comment: Can you var_dump both `json_encode($string)` and `json_decode($string)` ?

Comment: `json_decode($string)` is exactly the same as the original. `json_encode($string)` also looks exactly the same as the original, interestingly.

Comment: Urgh, that's too big a string to put in a question, but the question has no future value for new readers without being self-contained. Undownvoted, though. Does the same problem occur if you trim the string down to a few hundred characters?

Comment: That string you supplied get converted to a PHP stdClass's containing other stdClasses and arrays. In short its doing exactly whats it says on the box.

Comment: take a look at my curl version, I've update my answer

Answer (score 5):

```
$s = file_get_contents("http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=marketdatav2");
$s = json_decode($s);

print_r($s);
```

works like a charm

here is my curl version

```
$url = "http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=marketdatav2";
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
$data=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$s = json_decode($data);
print_r($s);
```

Comment: This did indeed work. I'm wondering why. Originally I was using `curl` to fetch the data.

Comment: Tried via crul, also works fine, do you need my example?

Comment: What do you think the issue is with my `curl` implementation.

Comment: you must to use CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to get data in a varialbe, and you don't need to cut anything ($ret = substr($ret, 0,-1);)

Comment: It's not necessary. I haven't tried it yet, but I think it will probably work. I'll try it when I get the chance, sometime soon.

Comment: Yes, I bet it will be the `RETURNTRANSFER` that will fix it. Good work, give your avatar a banana!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that page is being served as windows-1252, but I believe JSON must be in UTF-8. Try converting it to UTF-8 first, and then run it through `json_decode()`.

Comment: No probs. It might be worth editing your question to let us know how you are populating `$string` in the first place - @qwertmax says it works fine via `file_get_contents`.

Comment: I used `$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8");` to convert it and `json_decode()` did nothing...

Comment: `$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8");` solved the problem for me.